# np where with two conditions and met first

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, if-statement

I am trying to create a target variable based on 2 conditions. I have X values that are binary and X2 values that are also binary. My condition is whenver X changes from 1 to zero, we have one in y only if it is followed by a change from 0 to 1 in X2. If that was followed by a change from 0 to 1 in X then we don't do the change in the first place. I attached a picture from excel.

I also did the following to account for the change in X

```
df['X-prev']=df['X'].shift(1)
df['Change-X;]=np.where(df['X-prev']+df['X']==1,1,0)
# this is the data frame 
X=[1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
X2=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1]
df=pd.DataFrame()
df['X']=X
df['X2']=X2
```

however, this is not enough as I need to know which change came first after the X change. I attached a picture of the example.

Thanks a lot for all the contributions. [image: Example]

Comment: Please, replace your image by a plain text dataframe.

Comment: I updated my answer can you check it please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep rows that match your transition `(X=1, X+1=0)` and `(X2=1, X2-1=0)` then merge all selected rows to a list where a value of 0 means 'start a cycle' and 1 means 'end a cycle'.

But in this list, you can have consecutive start or end so you need to filter again to get only cycles of (0, 1). After that, reindex this new series by your original dataframe index and back fill with 1.

```
x1 = df['X'].sub(df['X'].shift(-1)).eq(1)
x2 = df['X2'].sub(df['X2'].shift(1)).eq(1)

sr1 = pd.Series(0, df.index[x1])
sr2 = pd.Series(1, df.index[x2])
sr = pd.concat([sr2, sr1]).sort_index()

df['Y'] = sr[sr.lt(sr.shift(-1)) | sr.gt(sr.shift(1))] \
            .reindex(df.index).bfill().fillna(0).astype(int)
```

```
>>> df

    X  X2  Y
0   1   0  0  # start here: (X=1, X+1=0) but never ended before another start
1   1   0  0
2   0   0  0
3   0   0  0
4   1   0  0  # start here: (X=1, X+1=0)
5   0   0  1  # <- fill with 1
6   0   0  1  # <- fill with 1
7   0   0  1  # <- fill with 1
8   0   0  1  # <- fill with 1
9   0   1  1  # end here: (X2=1, X2-1=0) so fill back rows with 1
10  0   1  0
11  0   1  0
12  0   1  0
13  0   1  0
14  0   0  0
15  0   0  0
16  0   1  0  # end here: (X2=1, X2-1=0) but never started before
17  0   0  0
18  0   0  0
19  0   0  0
20  1   0  0
21  1   0  0  # start here: (X=1, X+1=0)
22  0   0  1  # <- fill with 1
23  0   0  1  # <- fill with 1
24  0   0  1  # <- fill with 1
25  0   0  1  # <- fill with 1
26  0   0  1  # <- fill with 1
27  0   1  1  # end here: (X2=1, X2-1=0) so fill back rows with 1
28  0   1  0
29  0   1  0
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In the above example you had ones whenever X2 is one. What I am looking for is to change y from 1 to zero after the first X2 changes to1

Comment: I'll check that.

Comment: Hi Corralien! I was wondering if you have any thoughts

Comment: I can't find a solution :-(. Is it possible to have (X, X2) equal to (1, 1) in the same row? It can help very much if this combination is impossible. In you example, there is no (1, 1)

Comment: unfourtunatly yes !thanks for your time. I really appreciate it

Comment: How do you resolve a such case : (1, 0) (0, 0) (1, 1) (0, 0) (0, 1)

Comment: how to drop a case when they are all equal?

Comment: You beat my brains out! I hope this time is the right one:). I hope you will understand my explanation (English is not my best skill. lol). Try each line step by step with your sample to understand what I had mean to do.

Comment: Thanks for your help! you are a genius person!